# How to refer to Google translate sound button in VBA

Tags: vba

I need to refer to Google translate sound button in VBA. I've tried this way: .getElementByID("sgt-src-listen").Click but I received an error "Object required".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
.document.getElementById("gt-speech").Click
```

This assumes the link in question take you to [this](https://translate.google.co.uk/m/translate) page.